# How can I use middleware to authorize my laravel Restfull API

Tags: php, laravel

I am using laravel/passport and I want to authorize my API endpoint Then
The result I'm receiving declares that a **route(user/login)** is not defined with status code 500 in postman

#### Route

**Route::get('all/users', 'UserController@index')->middleware('auth');**

#### Controller

```
    {  
        return new UserResource(User::findOrFail($id));
    }
```

#### User Model

````
use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;


class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable, HasApiTokens;
    
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password','balance','phone'
    ];

    
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ]; 
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

Route `user/login` declares in your application when you call `Auth::routes()` in your `web.php` file.

That error is returned because you are using `api` route and you have called `auth` middleware on it.

If you want to return just `401 unauthorized` response when unauthorized user tries to access api you have to use `auth` middleware with `api` guard.

See example and correct code below:

```
Route::get('all/users', 'UserController@index')->middleware('auth:api');
```

Comment: By using this route  ``` Route::get('all/users', 'UserController@index')->middleware('auth:api');``` The error is ** Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException: Route [auth/user] not defined. in file /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/imanage-rest-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php on line 420**

Comment: Then put `Auth::routes()` in `routes/web.php` file

Comment: my routes are in ``` routes/api.php ``` because I want rest APIs for android app by the way this is what comes out after putting ``` Auth::routes() ``` in my routesIn order to use the Auth::routes() method, please install the laravel/ui package. in file /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/imanage-rest-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Auth.php on line 56

Comment: as usual route names are dot separated and `auth/user` is not correct route name. find where you have placed `auth/user` and replace it with abort(401);

Comment: After using ** abort(401) ** error is gone but still, I can not verify the token and  get access to a specific route